# node-gyp - not finding library headers

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, node-gyp, gyp

I'm trying to use a the gstreamer framework in my node addon. I had the following to my to my binding.gyp, but when i run the build command it, the console states that the header is not found. When i compile my gstreamer files outside of node-gyp, it compiles successfully. Does anyone see something wrong with my binding file ?

console

```
hello.cc3:25: fatal error: gstreamermm.h: No such file or directory
```

binding.gyp

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "addon",
          "libraries": [
            "-lgstreamer-1.0", "-L/usr/inlcude/gstreamer-1.0/gst/"
          ],
      "sources": [ "hello.cc" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

compile command that works correctly, and that I'm trying to run

```
g++ main.c -o main `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0`
```

Update: 
Following @Mike Kinghan binding.gyp 
[image]

Comment: `-L` is for setting library path, to set includes location you should use `-I`, so it should look like `-I /usr/inlcude/gstreamer-1.0/gst`

Comment: @VTT, i changed to I, and the error remains

Comment: Shouldn't include dirs go into `include_dirs` gyp file section and library dirs. go into `library_dirs` section?

Comment: @VTT, Sorry, i don't understand. What do you mean by library_dirs?

Comment: @VTT do you have an example?

Answer (score 7):

> Does anyone see something wrong with my binding file?

Yes:

```
"libraries": [
            "-lgstreamer-1.0", "-L/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/"
          ],
```

The `"libraries"` element, in `binding.gyp` should include the libraries, specified in `-l` or
absolute filename form, that you want to link.

`-lgstreamer-1.0` is one of those. `-L/usr/inlcude/gstreamer-1.0/gst/`
is not. It is a linker option that will instruct the linker to search
for libraries specified in `-l` form in the directory `/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/`.

That is specifying a library search directory, so if it were needed, you should say so in
the `"library_dirs"` element:

```
"library_dirs": [
  "/usr/inlcude/gstreamer-1.0/gst/",
]
```

But you don't need it, because there are no libraries in `/usr/inlcude/gstreamer-1.0/gst/`.
All the files under `/usr/include` are C or C++ header files, not libraries. Libraries
are installed under `/lib`, `/usr/lib` or `/usr/local/lib`.

You say you can successfully compile a program with:

```
g++ main.c -o main `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0`
```

That works because as you may know,

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0
```

outputs the compiler and linker options needed to build a target that depends on
`gstreamer-1.0`

Let's have a look:

```
$ pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0
-pthread -I/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 \
-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include \
-lgstreamer-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
```

Then let's use that information to write `binding.gyp`. (On your system it might differ from mine):

**binding.gyp**

```
{
    "targets": [
    {
        "target_name": "addon",
        "include_dirs": [
            "/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0",
            "/usr/include/glib-2.0",
            "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include"
        ],
        "libraries": [
            "-lgstreamer-1.0",
            "-lgobject-2.0",
            "-lglib-2.0"
        ],
        "sources": [ "hello.cc" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

(Have we forgotten the `-pthread` option emitted by `pkg-config`? No. `node-gyp` passes
it the compiler and linker by default)

With this `binding.gyp`, your build should look something like mine:

```
$ node-gyp configure build
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.4.0
gyp info using node@4.7.2 | linux | x64
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python2
gyp info spawn args [ '/usr/share/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/imk/develop/so/scrap/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/share/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/include/nodejs/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/usr/include/nodejs',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/share/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/imk/develop/so/scrap',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
make: Entering directory '/home/imk/develop/so/scrap/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/addon/hello.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/addon.node
  COPY Release/addon.node
make: Leaving directory '/home/imk/develop/so/scrap/build'
gyp info ok
```

Note furthermore, `pkg-config` tells you that the correct compiler include-path 
to locate gstreamer-1.0 header files is:

```
/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0
```

not:

```
/usr/incude/gstreamer-1.0/gst/
```

And we have followed that advice in our `binding.gyp`. Therefore
in your source code you will write, e.g.

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
```

and not:

```
#include <gst.h>
```

**Later**

Now your compiler cannot locate `<gst/gstconfig.h>`

One possible cause is that you didn't faithfully copy
the necessary include-directories reported for *your* system by:

```
pkg-config --cflags gstreamer-1.0
```

into the `include_dirs` list of your `binding-gyp`. Possibly you
just copied the ones from my example. My example, giving directories:

```
-I/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 \
-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include
```

was run on Ubuntu 17.04, in which `gst/gstconfig.h` is in fact
installed in `/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0`. But on Ubuntu 16.04,
for example:-

```
$ pkg-config --cflags gstreamer-1.0
-pthread -I/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0 \
-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 \
-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include
```

we get the additional include directory:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/include
```

and `gst/gstconfig.h` is indeed installed there. Check that you are using
the correct include directories that `pkg-config` reports on your system and
correct your `binding.gyp` if necessary.

If you *were* using the correct `pkg-config` results, then it would appear that your
`gstreamer-1.0` dev package has a defective `gstreamer-1.0.pc` file providing incorrect
`pkg-config` info. To work around that, ask your distro's package manager to show you
where the dev package really installed `gst/gstconfig.h`. E.g. for Ubuntu 16.04:

```
$ dpkg -L libgstreamer1.0-dev | grep gst/gstconfig
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/include/gst/gstconfig.h
```

Then add the required path prefix (e.g. `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/include`)
to the `include_dirs` of your `binding.gyp`.

Comment: I'm still getting some build errors. My library locations are the same as yours. see updated question. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @AJ_: Can you copy the project to Github? I am trying to start with this and looking for a good starting point.