# Node-gyp/C++ import shared library (.so)

Tags: c++, binding, static-libraries, node-gyp

Importing a shared library (.so) doesn't seem to be an easy task. I tried to follow the instructions in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46027121/node-gyp-not-finding-library-headers), but I really can't get it to work. Building without the library [RF24](https://tmrh20.github.io/RF24/RPi.html) is working. Followed their build instructions which produced the following filesets in the `/usr/local/lib` folder

```
librf24-bcm.so        librf24.so        librf24.so.1     librf24.so.1.3  
librf24.so.1.3.1      node_modules      python2.7        python3.5
```

In my .cpp file I include the library like this

```cpp
#include <RF24.h> // also tested "" instead of <>
```

My **binding.gyp** looks as like this

```json
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "includes":     [ "../auto.gypi"               ],
      "sources":      [ "../../src/myfile.cpp"       ],
      "include_dirs": [ "../../src"                  ],
      "library_dirs": [ "/usr/local/lib"             ],
      "libraries":    [ "-llibrf24"                  ],
      "cflags!":      [ "-fno-exceptions"            ],
      "cflags":       [ "-std=c++11", "-fpermissive" ],
      "cflags_cc!":   [ "-fno-rtti"                  ] 
    }
  ],
  "includes": [
    "../auto-top.gypi"
  ]
}
```

The compiling error is

```
myfile.cpp:2:18: fatal error: RF24.h: No such file or directory
```

I also tried using the files complete names in the *libraries* section, e.g. `librf24.so.1.3.1`, and without the `-l` flag. Also switched the *library_dirs* entry to *include_dirs*. Still the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to this [article](https://medium.com/@tarkus/how-to-call-c-c-code-from-node-js-86a773033892) I was able to figure it out. The RF24 build also has written the according header files to `/user/local/include/RF24`.

Updated the **binding.gyp** to

```
"include_dirs": [
  "../../src",
  "/usr/local/include/RF24"
],
"libraries": [
  "/usr/local/lib/librf24.so.1.3.1"
]
```

At least the addon is compiling without errors and warnings.